# Failed to compile. static/css/main.b6d8a2cb.css from Css Minimizer plugin TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

PS C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\web technology\NCT\carrental> npm run build

> carrental@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

static/css/main.b6d8a2cb.css from Css Minimizer plugin
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')

the react app runs fine on the development server but shows this error when I try to build it for production ready. crosses checked 100 times, nothing seems to work. the static/css/main.b6d8a2cb.css isn't part of my project.

Comment: Check the index.css or app.css file maybe mistake is in there.

Comment: Do you have something custom in your build configuration? If yes, please post it.

Comment: No. I do not have any custom.

Answer (score 0):

Check all the custom css file (including app.css and index.css) that you have added in your project and look for any missing comments. I had used a custom css file where i had forgot to comment out a few lines properly.